# RegEx matching multiple strings with StartWith and EndWith strings in a long string

Tags: c#, regex, string

**PROBLEM**

I have this super long string (in real world its over 3000 lines long)

```
0 PAGE TEST
1 PROPERTY TESTPROP
1 PROPERTY TESTPROP2
1 PROPERTY TESTPROP3

0 PAGE TEST2
1 PROPERTY TESTPROP13
1 PROPERTY TESTPROP223
1 PROPERTY TESTPROP3

0 VIDEO TESTVD
1 PROPERTY TESTPROP1323
1 PROPERTY TESTPROP223
1 PROPERTY TESTPROP3211
```

so basically what i want to do is : get all this parts in one List

*EDIT* i want to have something like this e.g

```
string str1 = "0 PAGE TEST1... ", 
string str2 = "0 PAGE TEST2..." 
..
```

and this strings should be in one list.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

here is my code

```
  var start_with_line = $"{level} {value} "; // Is usually "0 PAGE "
  var end_with_line = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(Environment.NewLine, 2)); // Is usually "\r\n\r\n" 

  var expression = $@"\{start_with_line}.+\{end_with_line}"; // Is equivalent to "\0 PAGE.+\\r\n\r\n"
  var matches = content.GetPagesFromContent(expression);
```

and here is my "GetPagesFromContent" method

```
    private static List<string> GetPagesFromContent(this string content, string expression)
    {
        var list = new List<string>();

        var matches = Regex.Matches(content, expression); // I get 0 matches here
        foreach (Match match in matches)
            list.Add(match.Value);

        return list;
    }
```

Comment: *"so basically what i want to do is : get all this parts in one List"* what do you actually mean by this? what's your expected output?

Comment: Why not splitting the string on `\n` and then each line on ` ` (space)?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko could you please give me an example (sorry , i'm a noob here and in programming)

Comment: Try `Regex.Split(content, @"(?>\r\n?|\n){2,}")`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, it works but i have no idea what i just copy pasted there. If its not too much work could you please explain me your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
private static List<string> GetPagesFromContent(this string content, string level)
{
    return Regex.Split(content, @"(?>\r\n?|\n){2,}")
        .Where(x => x.StartsWith(level))
        .ToList();
}
```

The regex matches 2 or more occurrences of CRLF, CR or LF sequences (an atomic group is used to forbid backtracking into the group pattern) and the string is split with those matches.

You might consider trimming off whitespace before running the regex with `Trim()`.

Comment: I edited my question. The thing is : your expression returns all "parts" regardless if there is "0 PAGE " at the begining or "0 SOMETHINGELSE".

Comment: @OverZer0 Add `.Where(x => x.StartsWith("0 PAGE"))` after `Split(...)`